# how to i find the location of a letter in an array then use the same location in another array for encryption using only arrays and loops

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I have created my encryption cipher from a user keyword. I am now trying to encrpyt some text such as "hello" using the cipher. I have got half way through and I know what I want to do but I dont know how to implement it? I have looped through the input text and the alphabet and once they match, I then want to use the location in the array to then go into the same location in the cipher array and print the letter from there. Example is below.

```
String input = "HELLO";
String output;

char[] alphToChar2 = alphabet.toCharArray();
char[] cipher2 = cipher;
char[] textasarray = input.toCharArray();


for(int j = 0; j<textasarray.length; j++) { //loop through text
    for (int i = 0; i<alphToChar2.length; i++) { // loop through alphabet
     {
        if (alphToChar2[j] == textasarray[i]); //if alphabet letter is equal to text letter
            for(int p = 0; p<cipher.length; p++) //looping through cipher
```

Then I want to use the location of that letter in the alphabet and encrypt with the letter that is in the same location in the encryption array.

For example 'H' is in position 7 in the alphabet array. Now I want to use position 7 in the cipher array and print it out to the output. Should I print out to new array then convert that array back to string for encryption.

Comment: then just put the ciphertext as the position in the key that you generated in your previous question

Comment: sorry i dont know what you mean.. could you explain a bit further

Comment: In your previous not closed (marked as accepted) question, you used to call a cipher array, that actually must be key array, anyway. Consider this array and message DAY. D=4 then encrypted version of D is cipher[D], cipher[A] and cipher[y] by indexing using integer values D-A..

Answer (score 0):

From what I get you want to print on the screen position 7 in your cipher: for that I don't think you need the last for loop. You could just print on the screen cipher2[i].